# connect() method not found in perl module "Net::SSH::Expect"

Tags: perl

I need to use some perl function in module `Net::SSH::Expect` the module description told the method `connect()` will remain the connection until method `close()` called. But I get an error

> perl can't locate object method connect" via package `Net::SSH::Expect`

Comment: I am writing a script to verify or change about 100+ unix servers' password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the module description told the method `connect()` will remain the connection until method `close()` called

You need to read [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Expect) again. It doesn't say that at all

There is no `connect` method; you need to call

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new( ... )
```

with the appropriate parameters

Comment: "Once an ssh connection was started using the connect() method it will remain open until you call the close() method." This is copied from description, or any misunderstanding ?

Comment: @Harvey: I can see how that could be confusing but it is an error and no `connect` method is documented. How can you write a call to `connect` if the parameters are undocumented?